# Como inserir no banco com prepared statements? Problema com ID

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou com problemas de contagem de colunas pois não sei como inserir os dados por `PDO` quando tem um `id AUTO_INCREMENT` que vem antes da variável `nome`. Não sei exatamente como inserir o `id` junto com os outros dados. Ai dá erro na contagem de colunas. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
$cadNome        = strip_tags($_POST['nome']);
$cadEmail       = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$cadTelefone    = strip_tags($_POST['telefone']);
$cadCeular      = strip_tags($_POST['celular']);
$cadCidade      = strip_tags($_POST['cidade']);
$cadDatepicker  = strip_tags($_POST['datepicker']);
$cadEstimada    = strip_tags($_POST['estimada']);
$cadComentarios = strip_tags($_POST['comentarios']);
$cadData        = 'NOW()';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO wp_contato VALUES(:nome, :email, :telefone, :celular, :cidade, :datepicker, :estimada, :comentarios, :datacontato)');

$stmt->execute(array( 
                ':nome'         => $cadNome,
                ':email'        => $cadEmail,
                ':telefone'     => $cadTelefone,
                ':celular'      => $cadCeular,
                ':cidade'       => $cadCidade,
                ':datepicker'   => $cadDatepicker,
                ':estimada'     => $cadEstimada,
                ':comentarios'  => $cadComentarios,             
                ':datacontato'  => $cadData
                ));
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilize `NULL` antes do parâmetro nome.

O `AUTO_INCREMENT` se encarrega do resto!

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO wp_contato VALUES(NULL, :nome, :email, :telefone, :celular, :cidade, :datepicker, :estimada, :comentarios, :datacontato)');
```

Comment: Já resolvi. Só esperando o sistema autorizar para marcar como melhor resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: Show! Qualquer dúvida é só perguntar!